# Transparent item

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I am using `\enumerate` in beamer. I would like to use this slide (with the enumeration) several times with only one item non-transparent (as usual) and the rest transparent - how to do the rest transparent, is there any command for this?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example that shows what you have so far? Thank you!

Comment: `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`

Comment: \documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> a
\item<2-> b
\item<3-> c
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Comment: For example this, and I would like to have e.g. a and c to be transparent and b visible. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-` in `<1->` means that this element should be visible until the end of the frame. I you want a to be covered again, simply use `<1>`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame} 
    \begin{itemize} 
        \item<1> a 
        \item<2> b 
        \item<3> c 
    \end{itemize} 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can this be done locally?

So that we have certain frames with \setbeamercovered{transparent} and certain frames without transparent.

Comment: @ShihabKhan Sure, just put a group around all the frames this should apply `{\setbeamercovered{transparent} \begin{frame}...\end{frame}}`