# How to get transparent examples in linguex

Tags: beamer, transparency, linguex

In a slide I want to explain each linguistic gloss point by point. When focusing on one sentence, I want the rest to be made transparent(translucent?), as would happen here with itemize(taken from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238692/transparent-item))

How do I accomplish the same using linguex? Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{linguex}
\setbeamercovered{transparent} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}

   \ex. \a. This is a sentence. Focus here.
        \b. Now focus here while the above fades away.

\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

EDIT: To add to the above question, what I also want to achieve is to show an already existing frame between every flash of the sentence. I'm not sure how to get this to work with existing `itemize` either so here's a probably incorrect MWE for linguex.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{linguex}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent} 

    \begin{document} 
    
    \begin[label=blurb]{frame}
         Show this between each example
    \end{frame}

    \begin[label=blurb-2]{frame}

       \ex. \uncover<+>{\a. This is a sentence. Focus here.}
            \uncover<+>{\b. Now focus here while the above fades away.}

    \end{frame}

    % Now show a previous slide
    \againframe{blurb}

    % Now show the second example, with first one translucent
    \againframe{blurb-2}

    % Ideally be able to do this over and over
\end{document}
```

Using the same techniques as before(the `<1>`, `<2>`) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using beamer overlays:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{linguex}
\setbeamercovered{transparent} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}

   \ex. \uncover<+>{\a. This is a sentence. Focus here.}
        \uncover<+>{\b. Now focus here while the above fades away.}

\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Venkat You're welcome!

Comment: Argh I've run into another bigger issue, I'm going to add some stuff to my above question since its quite long and needs another MWE :/

Comment: @Venkat If you have a new question, please use the "ask question" button on the top right to ask a new question